# How to find smallest rectangle in image using opencv python?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, keras

hello im trying to extract license plate from car, I m trying to filter out all rectangles in the image except for the rectangle that contains text and then display it. However I'm not sure how to achieve this. For now all my code is doing is just displaying any rectangle it finds , which on some images it displays windshield instead. Can someone please explain how to display the smallest rectangle?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

#import imutils

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhance
from skimage import color, data, restoration
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
import pytesseract
import PIL.ImageOps
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'


def main (img):
    print('flflfl')
    img = cv2.imread(img,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    print(img)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (600,400) )
    img = cv2.resize(img, (600,400) )
    threshold = 180 # to be determined
    _, img_binarized = cv2.threshold(img, threshold, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    pil_img = Image.fromarray(img_binarized)


    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 13, 15, 15)

    edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)
    thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, 1, 1, 11, 2)
    #contours = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    #contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
    contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]
    screenCnt = None

    gaussian_blur_license_plate = cv2.GaussianBlur(
        img, (5, 5), 0)

    for c in contours:

        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.018 * peri, True)


        if len(approx) == 4:
            
            screenCnt = approx

            break

    if screenCnt is None:
        detected = 0
        print ("No contour detected")
    else:
         detected = 1

    if detected == 1:
        cv2.drawContours(img, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)

    mask = np.zeros(gray.shape,np.uint8)
    new_image = cv2.drawContours(mask,[screenCnt],0,255,-1,)
    new_image = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask)

    (x, y) = np.where(mask == 255)
    (topx, topy) = (np.min(x), np.min(y))
    (bottomx, bottomy) = (np.max(x), np.max(y))
    Cropped = gray[topx:bottomx+1, topy:bottomy+1]
```

Comment: I see that you have tried to find the smallest rectangle in the image with the help of contour Area. Is it possible to share an image on which you are trying to find.

Comment: im trying to check if the smallest rectangle in image contains text or not and if it does then display it

Answer (score 0):

you could find the smallest rectangle by looking at the contour areas:

```
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    #code for finding the smalles area
```

hope that might help you